# In an LDAP 'lastlogon' lookup how do I decipher the result?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm using a PHP script to grab data from Active Directory using LDAP..

When I get the user values for 'lastlogon' I get a number like 129937382382715990

I've tried to figure out how to get the date/time from this but have no idea, can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this comment on the [PHP: LDAP Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php#61144) page.

> All of them are using "Interval" date/time format with a value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC, and a value of 0 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 9223372036854775807, indicates that the account never expires): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> So if you need to translate it from/to UNIX timestamp you can easily calculate the difference with:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $datetime1 = new DateTime('1601-01-01');
> $datetime2 = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
> $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
> echo ($interval->days * 24 * 60 * 60) . " seconds\n";
> ?>
> ```
>
> The difference between both dates is 11644473600 seconds. Don't rely on floating point calculations nor other numbers that probably were calculated badly (including time zone or something similar).
>
> Now you can convert from LDAP field:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $lastlogon = $info[$i]['lastlogon'][0];
> // divide by 10.000.000 to get seconds from 100-nanosecond intervals
> $winInterval = round($lastlogon / 10000000);
> // substract seconds from 1601-01-01 -> 1970-01-01
> $unixTimestamp = ($winInterval - 11644473600);
> // show date/time in local time zone
> echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp) ."\n";
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is the number 100-nanosecond ticks since 1 January 1601 00:00:00 UT.

[System time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time) article in Wikipedia can give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$timeStamp = 129937382382715990;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeStamp);
```

EDIT ------

I just tried the following and noticed that this method wont work unless the clock on your machine is set 10 years in the future. Below is the code I used to prove the above pretty much useless unless you do more processing maybe..

```
$time = time();
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);  

echo "<br />";

$timeStamp = 129937382382715990;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeStamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using Pentaho. With a `Modified Javascript value` you can convert the values, `lastLogon` is the column I wanna convert from data stream:

```
calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTime(new Date("1/1/1601"));
base_1601_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

calendar.setTime(new Date("1/1/1970"));
base_1970_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

ms_offset = base_1970_time - base_1601_time;

calendar.setTimeInMillis( lastLogon / 10000 - ms_offset); //lastLogon is a column from stream
var converted_AD_time = calendar.getTime(); // now just add this variable 'converted_AD_time'  to the 'Fields' as a show in the image below
```

[image]